# Detect urls from a big string and add some text to the end of each url

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a big big string, like a body html from a web, and I want to recognize the urls and add some text to the end of the each url.

The things is, that is not for all of each urls, its only for urls that match with the pollyn text in some place inside of that url.

Like this: http://www.domine.com/something/pollyn/something/

And I need that will be: http://www.domine.com/something/pollyn/something/thisisthextadedd

I try with:

```
body = body.replace(/(pollyn)\/?/ig, '$1something');
```

But the problem with that, is that remplace the pollyn word.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

The solution was something like this:

```
function urlify(text) {
      var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
      return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        if(url.indexOf("pollyn") !== -1 || url.indexOf("poll") !== -1){
          url = url.replace('"',"");
          return url+"&something";
        }
        return url;
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a regex look behind query which is not natively supported in Javascript.  However, adapting the first of the solutions here: [mimic-lookbehind-javascript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), you can make something that does the right thing.

The remaining problem is what the URLs are terminated with.  For example if there is always a space after the URLs then something like this could work:

```
body=body.replace(/(\/pollyn\/.*?)?\/ /g, function(a,b){return b? b+"/test ":a;})
```

This searches for "/pollyn/" then allows for a lazy matching (the ".*?") of any characters until it finds a forward slash and a space.  It then will replace the forward slash and space with the text defined in the lambda function (which needs to also include the forward slash at the start and space at the end).

Comment: I made something like this:

function urlify(text) {
      var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
      return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        if(url.indexOf("pollyn") !== -1 || url.indexOf("poll") !== -1){
          url = url.replace('"',"");
          return url+"&thomething';
        }
        return url;
      });
    }